# Configurable Product no options loaded "configurableWidget is undefined"

Tags: configurable-product

there is a problem we cannot solve and even not reproduce correct.
the error seems only to appear in firefox. on the product page sometimes the options are not loaded. it looks like this:
[image: Text]

Hit Reload, open the product directly with the link or using another browser works fine:
[image: Text]

The Console says "Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "element", configurableWidget is undefined"
[image: Text]

Can anyone reproduce the error or even figured out, whats going wrong there?

Comment: Try to disable the third party extension related to product view page and debug, so you get idea is this related to which one.

Comment: You hit it! Thanks